# How can I calculate acceleration from displacement and time?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, displacement

How can I calculate acceleration from displacement and time, assuming a velocity at rest? Is there any formula to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplest case of linear motion with uniform acceleration $a$, the displacement $x(t)$ is given by:

$$x(t)=x_0+v_0t+\frac12 at^2$$

From any given $x(t)$ and $t$ (and $x_0$, $v_0$) $a$ can be easily calculated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the acceleration relates to the position through a second order timer deivative.

$$\mathbf a=\frac{\text d^2\mathbf x}{\text dt^2}$$

I am not sure what you mean by "assuming a velocity at rest" though. If you have the position as a function of time then the velocity is also determined by a derivative:
$$\mathbf v=\frac{\text d\mathbf x}{\text dt}$$
so you don't assume anything about the velocity given the position as a function of time.

However, if you had the opposite problem of knowing the acceleration $\mathbf a(t)$ and you needed to determine the position $\mathbf x(t)$ from it, you would need to specify some sort of initial conditions of $\mathbf x(0)=\mathbf x_0$ and $\mathbf v(0)=\mathbf v_0$. If you wanted $\mathbf v0=0$ you could explore that.